# Why does this small protrusion from the shadow of a vertical edge appear in this set up?

Tags: optics, home-experiment, shadow

I am seeking an explanation to this observation concerned the shadow of a ball on a wall or a screen when the shadow of the ball is approaching the shadow of a vertical edge.

In this setup, the vertical edge is closer to the source of the light than the ball. The ball is closer to the wall and moves parallel to it.

[image]

When a ball moves parallel to the wall, its shadow appears differently as it comes closer to the vertical shadow. In particularly, a small protrusion appears to come from the shadow of the vertical edge toward the shadow of the ball. 
[image]

I understand that the overlapping between the penumbras from the two shadows can augment the shadow of the ball as it appears in the second image. But I do not have a clue why the small protrusion from the shadow of the vertical edge appears as the shadow of the ball approaches the vertical shadow (the right most image).